# Issues binding DataTable to DataGridView - am I missing a step?

Tags: c#, datagridview

in my Windows Forms application, I have a DataGridView which will be programatically bound via a DataTable from the code behind. I have been doing it this way for many weeks, but this was because I didn't manually specify the columns and column types in the DGV designer - so the columns were being created automatically when binding the table.

Once I manually give the column and column names, and set the DGV's AutoGenerateColumns property to false, then there is always just 1 row in the DGV after binding, and all values are null - so it seems the values from my DataTable don't seem to be mapping to the DGV. I've ensured the name of the columns in the DGV match the name of the columns in my DataTable.

Any ideas? Here's some code (can't copy and paste any code at the moment so here's a rough idea of what I have):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ID",typeof(long));
//etc...

var linqQuery = //perform linq query to get data

foreach (var data in linqQuery)
{
   dt.Rows.Add(data.ID,//etc);
}

dgv.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: If you're using LINQ to select all your relevant data, can you just set the DataSource property to the linqQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My own idiocy here. I didn't set the DataPropertyName. D'oh. Thanks!

Comment: yep even in the UI, it is editable drop down list not the selectable one i.e. slightly misleading!!!

Answer (score 1):

Since you turned AutoGenerateColumns of you need to set the DataPropertyName for each Column in your DGV to the matching Column Name in your DataSource.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this ..for mapping datagrid view columns to datatable ..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestWinApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }    
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet dsPlayerList = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("PlayerList");
            dsPlayerList.Tables.Add(dt);

            dt.Columns.Add("ID",typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name",typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("IP", typeof(string));

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["ID"] = 1;
            dr["Name"] = "Player 1";
            dr["Type"] = "Standard";
            dr["IP"] = "127.0.0.1";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["ID"] = 2;
            dr["Name"] = "Player 2";
            dr["Type"] = "Standard";
            dr["IP"] = "127.0.0.1";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dt.AcceptChanges();

            this.dgvPlayerList.AutoGenerateColumns = false;    
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            col.DataPropertyName = "Name";
            col.Name = "Name";
            col.HeaderText = "Name";                
            this.dgvPlayerList.Columns.Add(col);

            col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            col.DataPropertyName = "Type";
            col.Name = "Type";
            col.HeaderText = "Type";    
            this.dgvPlayerList.Columns.Add(col);

            this.dgvPlayerList.DataSource = dsPlayerList.Tables["PlayerList"];            
        }        
    }
}
```